# Air in Weed Eater Gas Line?

Tags: engine

My weed eater primer/gas line has more air in it than I think it should. It'll begin to start, but I don't think it's getting enough gas to keep going.

What's the best way to get the extra air out?

Comment: Do you have evidence that there is air in the line, or do you just not think it's getting enough power? Remember, if there WAS air in the line, the gas running through it under normal operating conditions should flush that air out. Might be better to post the symptoms and get people to help you diagnose it rather than jumping to assuming a specific problem.

Comment: The gas lines and primer bubble are clear.  I can see it at least 50% bubbles.  Plus the bubble was 90% air with 10% gas.

When I pulled the plug, it seemed pretty dry in there as well.  Have a feeling the carb is clogged.

Comment: Sounds more like the connection to the tank is plugged or loose, or the tank is oriented wrong, or the tank is almost empty. The air has to be being drawn into the line if you're seeing it, presumably from the top unless things are completely clogged there and it's drawing backward... Clogged carb would mean you weren't drawing gas, not that you'd be drawing air into that line... Do the bubbles _move_ in the gas line at all?

Comment: Yeah bubbles definitely move.  Didn't find any clogged lines.  1 was definitely clear, but I can check the other 2.

Comment: OK, that sounds like the problem is at the tank end of the fuel line. Something's delivering air when it should be delivering fuel.

Answer (score 1):

A routine repair of 2 cycle engines is replacement of the fuel line and the clear plastic bubble that is pumped to prime it(suck fuel into the line). Pumping the primer bubble will remove air from the line if everything is working. If you were not low on gas you had a leak in the fuel line.

Answer (score 0):

i just had problems with my trimmer not going to full power,i thought it  was arrestor screen, it was ok. i noticed that if i leaned the carburator against my arm the trimmer would throttle all the way up. i inspected everything and found a big bubble in the fuel line. i filled tank all the way and started to rev it back and forth eventually no bubble and the trimmer has had no problems